# Scheduler attach ERROR when replacing an existing executor !!! id:88

Tags: objective-c

Xcode show : 
Scheduler attach ERROR when replacing an existing executor !!! id:88
Scheduler attach ERROR when replacing an existing executor !!! id:88
Scheduler attach ERROR when replacing an existing executor !!! id:88
Scheduler attach ERROR when replacing an existing executor !!! id:88
Scheduler attach ERROR when replacing an existing executor !!! id:88
Scheduler attach ERROR when replacing an existing executor !!! id:88
Scheduler attach ERROR when replacing an existing executor !!! id:88

Comment: what is it ? ? ? ?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you hook the method [NSDate date]?

Scheduler allocate the thread will use time, if time change will happen.